# Jqgrid Add and Edit form property is not working

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am working with jqgrid but facing problem while add and edit. My jqgrid code looks like this..

```
 function setupGrid(){
    jQuery("#dataTable").jqGrid({
        url: "person/get",
        datatype: "json",
        loadonce : false,
        jsonReader: {root : "rows", repeatitems: false, id: "id"},
        colNames:['ID','First Name','Last Name', 'Address', 'Postcode'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'id',index:'id', width:20, sortType:"int"},
            {name:'firstName',index:'firstName', width:100, editable:true},
            {name:'lastName',index:'lastName', width:100, editable:true},
            {name:'address',index:'address', width:380, align:"right", editable:true},
            {name:'postcode',index:'postcode', width:100, align:"right", editable:true,editoptions:{size:25}
             }
        ],
        rowNum:4,
        rowList:[5,10,20,30],
        height:200,
        pager: "#pagingDiv",
        viewrecords: true,
        sortname: 'id',
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption: "Names and Addresses",
        rownumbers : true,
        ondblClickRow: function(rowid) {
            grid.jqGrid('editGridRow',rowid, editParam);
            return;
        }
    }).navGrid('#pager', 

        {add : true, edit : true, del: true, search:true,
            multipleSearch : true
        },

        {
            recreateform : true,
            width : 800, 
            url: 'person/test', 
            top: 350, 
            left:400,

            editCaption:"Edit Employee",
            viewPagerButtons :false,
            closeOnEscape:true,
            model : true,
            closeAfterEdit : true,
            topinfo : 'Top Info Test Edit',
            bottominfo : "Footer Info",
            checkOnSubmit : true,
        },

        {
            recreateform : true,
            width:300, 
            url:'person/test2', 
            top: 350, 
            left:400, 
            addCaption : "Add Employee",
            closeOnEscape:true,
            drag : true,
            model : true,
            topinfo : 'Top Info Test',
            closeAfterAdd : true,
        },


        {
            url : 'person/delete',
            mtype:"POST",
            deleteCaption : "Delete Employee"
        },

    {
            recreatefilter : true                   
    });


    jQuery("#dataTable").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : true});
}
```

My Problem is one i start application and click on jqgrid add button then it pick add property. After that if i click on edit but then it also pick the add button property.

Again if i start application again and this time if i chose edit button(Suppose i already have data in grid without hitting add button) this time edit form populate with edit property. Now click on add button now it pick edit form property. I could not understand what's going on.

Initially i did not use recreatefilter : true. But at time it has not worked. Later on i used recreatefilter : true. But result is same.

Can any body please tell me what i have to do to over come with this problem.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem. you could find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

remove  `recreateform : true,` and replace it by

```
beforeInitData: function () {
  $("#editmod" + this.id).remove();
}
```

Thanks to Oleg for posting this answer.